# From a hash map, How to replace different values into each "key" that appeared in the input sentence?

Tags: java, string, replace, hashmap, combinations

I have a hashmap `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>` (e.g. `Person-[p1,p2,p3]`),
and an input string:

```
"Person talked to Person about Person"
```

How to replace different values into each "*key*" that appeared in the input sentence?
I want the result should be:

```
"p1 talked to p2 about p3"

"p1 talked to p3 about p2"

"p2 talked to p1 about p3"

"p2 talked to p3 about p1"

"p3 talked to p2 about p1"

"p3 talked to p1 about p2"
```

(combination all possible combinations of k elements in n). Is that any method or library support for this replacement? :D

--

I've done at the step of generating a simple replacing, but still stucked at generating the Permutations.

```
public static void main (String[] args) { 
 
        HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> data = new HashMap<>();
        String test = "Person talked to Person about Person and Person";
        //Just to populate.
        ArrayList<String> input = new ArrayList<>();
        input.add("p1");
        input.add("p2");
        input.add("p3");
        data.put("Person", input);
        
        if (StringUtils.countMatches(test, "Person") > data.get("Person").size()) {
            System.out.println("Error: out of range");
        }else {
            for (int i=0 ; i<data.get("Person").size() ; i++) {
                 myReplace(test, "Person", data, i);
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static void myReplace(String input, String replaceValue, HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> data, int indexOfValue) {

        while (input.contains(replaceValue)) {
            
            if (indexOfValue >= data.get(replaceValue).size()-1) {
                indexOfValue = indexOfValue % data.get(replaceValue).size();
            }
            input = input.replaceFirst(replaceValue, data.get(replaceValue).get(indexOfValue));
            indexOfValue++;
        }
        System.out.println(input);
    }
```

Comment: Have you made an attempt? If so, show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a suggestion.  This is partially pseudo code so it will not compile.

The key is not to use a map but to simply generate permutations of the people talking.  For three people you have six permutations, four people, 24 permutations, `n` people, `n!` permutations.  Here are the ones for three people:

```
p1, p2, p3
p1, p3, p2
p2, p1, p3
p2, p3, p1
p3, p1, p2
p3, p2, p1
```

So search the web (or this site) for a permutation algorithm (there are many out there) and do the following:

```
ArrayList<String> input = new ArrayList<>();
input.add("p1");
input.add("p2");
input.add("p3");


while(input = getNextPermutation(input)) {
    String text = "Person talked to Person about Person";
    for ( String p : input) {
        text.replaceFirst("Person", p)
    }
    System.out.println(text);
}
```

The main challenge here will be integrating the permutation algorithm into the code.  It does **not** have to be done as in the example.

Comment: Yep, we have the same idea for dealing with generating a string but the permutation is a problem.

Comment: The algorithms are plentiful on the web.  A simple but highly inefficient approach is to generate all numbers from 123 to 321 and only keep those numbers that have the digits 1,2, and 3. There will be 6 of them

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. At first, I just looked into your code of replacing so I forgot your idea of using Permutation. My current idea is to generate all the permutation lists and run each of them. I'm back here, read again your first comment and well, you talked the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

More of a detailed comment on the accepted answer and your initial code - to truly move this around one-to-many, I would not use List but Set instead (guaranteeing that each subject is unique) if doing it this way.

On a different approach, I would just be working on the list itself or in my case array itself saving results once I know it's correct. And the array is not a 'plain' array in my case, it has an extra feature; arrays have the irritating property of *ending* but this one can rotate (I initially used it as a way to fade colours when generating histogram buckets that I wanted to 'fade'. Then I started using it frequently when generating test data for JUnits etc, a small array can generate any amount of test data for instance). In the simplest case you just use getNext() and when the pointer has passed the end index it just reverts to 0 again and that's pretty much it (I added some extra grab methods for different purposes).

A JUnit:

```
public class SpeakerTest {
    private static final String[] PERSONS = new String[] { "p1", "p2", "p3" };
    private static final ArrayRotator<String> ROTATOR = new ArrayRotator<>(PERSONS);
    private static final String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    private static final String SUBJECT_ = "subject ";
    private static final String TALKED_TO = " talked to ";

    @Test
    public void everyoneGetsToSpeakToTheOthers() {
        StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();

        int subjectIndex = 0; // points to the subject speaking
        int personsTalkedTo = 0; // how many each has talked to

        while (subjectIndex < PERSONS.length) {
            ROTATOR.getNext(); // the first person is always the subject self in our ordered array - skip it
            while (personsTalkedTo < PERSONS.length) {
                String adressedPerson = ROTATOR.getNext();
                if (personsTalkedTo != PERSONS.length - 1) { // we know we always want to grab one less than the actual length
                    message.append(SUBJECT_).append(PERSONS[subjectIndex]).append(TALKED_TO).append(adressedPerson).append(NL);
                }
                personsTalkedTo++;
            }

            subjectIndex++; // move to the next subject
            personsTalkedTo = 0; //..which so far talked to noone

            // just print it and reset the builder
            System.out.println(message.toString());
            message.delete(0, message.length());
        }
    }
}
```

produces output

```
subject p1 talked to p2
subject p1 talked to p3

subject p2 talked to p3
subject p2 talked to p1

subject p3 talked to p1
subject p3 talked to p2
```

and it will work for any number of persons. If you want to save results in a map you can do this instead of printing.

The little Rotator tool that you feed with any array of anything which, again, is useful for many purposes:

```
public class ArrayRotator<T> {

    private final T[] array;
    private int index;
    private static final Random RANDOM = new Random(731111245);

    private enum Direction {
        FORWARD, BACKWARD
    }

    public enum RenderMethod {
        NEXT, RANDOM, PHASED_NEXT
    }

    private Direction direction;

    public ArrayRotator(T[] array) {
        if (array == null || array.length < 2) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("You need top ship an array of no less than 2 elements!");
        }
        this.array = array;
        index = -1;
        direction = Direction.FORWARD;
    }

    public T getNext() {
        index++;
        if (index > array.length - 1) {
            index = 0;
        }
        return array[index];
    }

    public T getRandom() {
        return array[RANDOM.nextInt((array.length - 1) + 1)];
    }

    public T getNextPhading() {
        if (direction == Direction.FORWARD) {
            index++;
        } else {
            index--;
            if (index < 0) {
                direction = Direction.FORWARD;
                index++;
            }
        }
        if (index > array.length - 1) {
            direction = Direction.BACKWARD;
            index--;
        }
        return array[index];
    }

    public T[] get(RenderMethod method, int numberOfItems) {
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
        switch (method) {
            case NEXT:
                for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++) {
                    list.add(getNext());
                }
                return (T[]) list.toArray();
            case RANDOM:
                for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++) {
                    list.add(getRandom());
                }
                return (T[]) list.toArray();
            case PHASED_NEXT:
                for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++) {
                    list.add(getNextPhading());
                }
                return (T[]) list.toArray();
            default: throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Not supported mode %s", method.name()));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: ..or in this case you could actually do it straight on with a stream, an equals filter and a group by thinking this over once more.. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to use Java Streams in this scenario and generate the needed result. Here is the working solution -

```
public void test(){
    String p1 = "P1";
    String p2 = "P2";
    String p3 = "P3";

    List<String> personList = List.of(p1, p2, p3);
    List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<>();

    personList
            .stream()
            .forEach(px -> personList // 1st Loop over all Person List
                    .stream()
                    .filter(not(px::equals)) // Filter to exclude the px person
                    .forEach(py -> personList // 2nd loop over filtered Person List
                            .stream()
                            .filter(p -> !(p.equals(px) || p.equals(py))) // Filter to exclude both px and py
                            .forEach(pz ->  // 3rd loop over filtered Person List
                                    resultList.add(String.format("%s talked to %s about %s", px, py, pz))) // Prepare the result
                    )
            );

    for(String result: resultList) {
        System.out.println(result);
    }

}
```

---

Generated Output

```
P1 talked to P2 about P3
P1 talked to P3 about P2
P2 talked to P1 about P3
P2 talked to P3 about P1
P3 talked to P1 about P2
P3 talked to P2 about P1
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it using replaceFirst. And assuring you only have three inputs

```
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> data = new HashMap<>();
    
    //Just to populate.
    ArrayList<String> input = new ArrayList<>();
    input.add("p1");
    input.add("p2");
    input.add("p3");

    data.put("Person", input);
    data.put("Person2", input);
    data.put("Person3", input);

    String test = "Person talked to Person about Person";

    //End of populate

    data.forEach((k, v) -> {
        String newS = test.replaceFirst("Person", v.get(0));
        newS = newS.replaceFirst("Person", v.get(1));
        newS = newS.replaceFirst("Person", v.get(0));
        System.out.println(newS);
    });
```

Comment: Obviously, it doesn't work but thank you for your contribution.